# JavaScript function not defined in c# code

Tags: javascript, c#

I am working with VS, a web form application, and I want to generate in the code-behind (C#) a JavaScript function defined in a JavaScript file in the project,.
I have tried different ways ,such as this line of code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "Function_Name", true);
```

However, it can't resolve the name of my function since it's "not defined" as it's shown as a JavaScript error. But it works fine with a simple line of JavaScript code put in the `Function_Name` field (like `alert("something")`).

Any help with this please?

Comment: `Function_Name` !== `function_Name` - different capitalisation.

Comment: Function_Name ,function_Name , that's just a label . the problem is that the name of my defined function is not known in c# code . I edited the question .

Comment: If you use two *different* names for the function, and different capitalisation counts as *different*, then you would get "not defined". Again, the two are not the same. If that's *not* the case for you, then your question doesn't make it clear.

Comment: @VLAZ i know that's undeniable , when i call my function , it shows it's not defined , with it's same name for sure , (i edited the question )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#

define your javascript inside the C# code as text

```
Type type = this.GetType();
String key = "CallMyFunction";
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(type, key))
{
  StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
  script.AppendLine("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
  script.AppendLine("  function Function_Name() {");
  script.AppendLine("    frmMain.Message.value = 'Hello World';");
  script.AppendLine("  }");
  script.AppendLine("</script>");

  cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, key, script.ToString(), false);
}
```

or read your javascript from a .js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Function_Name() {
    frmMain.Message.value = 'Hello World';
  }
</script>
```

```
Type type = this.GetType();
String key = "CallMyFunction";
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(type, key) && File.Exists(path))
{
  string script = File.ReadAllText(path);

  cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, key, script, false);
}
```

HTML - Body

```
<body>
  <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
    <input type="text" id="Message" />
    <input type="button" value="Click!" onclick="Function_Name()" />
  </form>
</body>
```

If you need a one-liner:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "function Function_Name() { frmMain.Message.value='Hello World'; }", true);
```

or

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">function Function_Name() { frmMain.Message.value='Hello World'; }</script>", false);
```

EDIT:

Using includes

```
String includeKey = "MyInclude";
String includeFile = "/myInclude.js";
String scriptKey = "CallMyFunction";
String script = "Function_Name();"; //Function inside your included js file.
Type type = GetType();
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

//register the js file containing the function
if (!cs.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(includeKey))
{
    cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(includeKey, includeFile);
}

//register the script to call the function 
if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(scriptKey))
{
    cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, scriptKey, script, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! that works fine , but what can i do when there are imports in the JavaScript code ? , because that generates errors in this situation .

Comment: thanks , that can be resolved with a single line in html file by adding type="module"     <script type="module" src="./src/index.js"></script>"